# Pseudo elements transition on IE 11 ignores padding

Tags: css, internet-explorer, debugging, transition

Trying to do a button hover effect I stumbled upon this weird bug on IE.

It's happening even on IE11.

When you hover over the button the pseudo elements 'jump' their transition.
If you remove the padding, it stops!

I've been trying to work around it the whole afternoon, but I can't seem to find the problem.

Here's the demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVwRKL

```
HTML
<a href="http://##" title="yeah">Live Button</a>

CSS
body
{
  padding: 5em;
  margin: 0;
}

a{
  padding: 1em 1em;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px blue;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

a::before,
a::after
{
  transition: width 0.4s ease, height 0.4s ease 0.4s, opacity 0.4s ease;
  content: " ";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 3px green;
  display: inline-block;
}

a::after
{
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}

a::before
{
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

a:hover::before,
a:hover::after
{
  transition-delay: 0.4s, 0s, 0.7s;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not seeing a big difference between IE 11 and Chrome. Could you share another demo, with as little code as possible, that emphasizes the issue?

Comment: When you view the box in IE11 it looks like a portion of the 3px border that is being animated is showing briefly in the middle of the box then moving to the outside of it. It happens quickly. I am assuming this is what the OP is talking about

Comment: does giving the a a line-height instead of top and bottom padding help?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the comments. @JonathanSampson on chrome the animation is smooth, on IE is jumps as soon as you hover it jumps to the middle of the button.

Comment: hey @CarolMcKay, the line-height didn't work. I'm pretty lost on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you ever got an answer to this Marlon but I've just come across basically the same issue with IE. Thankful I've managed to figure out the oddity in IE that is causing the issue.

It appears to be when you are mixing your measurement prefixes i.e. px, %, em, vw, etc...

In my issue I was going from a **vw** to **px** - this worked fine everywhere except IE. As soon as I changed my **vw** to a **px** everything worked fine.

In your example above it was even less obvious to spot. You have the before/after set to a width of **100% - % being the measurement.** Then, in the hover state, you had them both simply set to **0 (zero) with no measurement**. This is where the problem is because no measurement **isn't the same** as % which IE appears to struggle to figure out (?!?!?!). As soon as you add the % to the width/height on the hover state it works fine.

See working example here with the adjusted width/height: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyNWzw

**Previous CSS**

```
a:hover::before,
a:hover::after
{
  transition-delay: 0.4s, 0s, 0.7s;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

**Adjusted CSS**

```
a:hover::before,
a:hover::after
{
  transition-delay: 0.4s, 0s, 0.7s;
  width: 0%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Typically I would also never bother adding a measurement when the value is 0 (zero) but I guess if you're using transitions then IE requires it to match.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Man, I just tested your solution on an old jsFiddle I had with the issue, it worked. Thanks for taking the time to reply.